# What to do with common jars in EAR for JBoss?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

We have 2 web applications.
And we are going to move them to EAR file.
Is it possible to move common jars from these two web applications to some separate directory in EAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can put shared jars in the lib folder within the EAR on JBoss 5

ear/lib/common.jar

Comment: Is this standard place for all application servers?  
We are going to deploy our applications on JBoss and Weblogic.

Comment: No, it is different per App server. On Weblogic, utility JAR files go into the APP-INF/lib directory

Comment: I checked approach with "ear/lib/common.jar" both on jboss(5) and weblogic(10.3.2) - it works on both application servers.